# How to correctly make a condition by using the class property ?

Tags: javascript

How to change the logic of the method "kick" in the class "Team". He chooses a random target among  the team with heroes (if she is alive) and deals damage to her, so the battle between the two teams ("team1" and "team2" in the class "Game") happen . It is necessary that the goal of the same type be selected first and the "kick" was used to it: "archer" from "theam1" "kick" "archer" from "theam2" then back. And if "archer" dies, then select target by accident.

Pseudo code, what I mean:

```
var simpletypeUnit = this.members.type[i];
if(simpletypeUnit.type == target.type && this.isAlive) {
  simpletypeUnit.kick(target)
}else {
 //random target selection 
}
```

```js
//constructor for creating a unit
function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage,type) {
    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.currentHealth = maxHealth;
    this.basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this.type = type;
}
/*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
 than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
Unit.prototype.isAlive = function () {
    return this.currentHealth > 0;
};
/* a method that
 shows the level of health*/
Unit.prototype.getFormattedHealth = function () {
    return this.currentHealth + "/" + this.maxHealth + " HP";
};
/*a method that returns the base damage of the hero and damage to the
 weapon (if it is set)*/
Unit.prototype.getDamage = function () {
    return this.basicDamage;
};
/* The method of hitting
 the hero for the chosen purpose*/
Unit.prototype.kick = function (target) {
    if (this.isAlive()) {
        target.currentHealth = Math.max(0,
            target.currentHealth - this.getDamage());
        console.log(this.type + " hit " + this.type);
    }
    console.log(this.type + " hit " + target.type);
    return this;
};
/*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
 with them*/
Unit.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Type - " + this.type + ", is alive - " +
        this.isAlive() + ", " + this.getFormattedHealth() +
        ', hero current damage - ' + this.getDamage() + ' points';
};
/*the constructors of the main types of units  which we will use*/
function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "archer";
}
function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "swordsman";
}
function Mage(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "mage";
}
Archer.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
Swordsman.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
Mage.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
/*We create units of which we will then write to the teams.
 Three units per team*/
var archer = new Archer(60, 5);
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10);
var mage = new Mage(40, 15);

var troll = new Archer(70, 5);
var orc = new Swordsman(150, 10);
var druid = new Mage(50, 15);

/*class for creating teams*/
function Team(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.members = [];
}
/*method for adding a new unit with an arbitrary number of units*/
Team.prototype.addMember = function (...members) {
    this.members.push(...members);
};
/*method of life of the team, if all participants have
 "currentHealth" <0 then this method = "false"*/
Team.prototype.isAlive = function () {
    return this.members.some(n => n.isAlive());
};
/*The method of random choice of the target, if the hero is alive,
then the target is randomly chosen and damage is done using
the "kick" method*/
Team.prototype.selectRandomTarget = function (targetTeam) {
    var numberOfMembers = targetTeam.members.length;
    var target = null;
    while(target == null || !target.isAlive())
    {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfMembers);
        target = targetTeam.members[randomIndex];
    }
    return target;
};
/*method of damage, we go through the array of  "members" and if the target
is alive, then we accidentally deal damage using the method "selectRandomTarget"*/
Team.prototype.kick = function(targetTeam) {
    console.log(`\nTeam ${this.name} is attacking`);

    for(var i=0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
        var singleMember = this.members[i];

        if(!this.isAlive()) break;
        if(!singleMember.isAlive()) continue;
        var target = this.selectRandomTarget(targetTeam);
        singleMember.kick(target);
    }
};
/*method to output information about the team*/
Team.prototype.toString = function () {
    var res = "Name of team - " + this.name +  '\n'
        + "life of a team : " + this.isAlive() + '\n'
        +"members :\n";
    for (var i=0; i<this.members.length; i++)
        res += this.members[i]+"\n";
    return  res;
};
/*create team 1 and add units to it*/
var team1 =  new Team('Alliance');
team1.addMember(archer,swordsman,mage);
/*create team 2 and add units to it*/
var team2 = new Team('Orcs');
team2.addMember(troll,orc,druid);

/*class that organizes a battle between two teams until
 "currentHealth" of all units in the team will not be zero*/
function Game(team1, team2) {
    this.team1 = team1;
    this.team2 = team2;
}
/*the method in which the battle occurs until the
 "isAlive" property of all participants of one of the commands
 is equal to "false"*/
Game.prototype.battle = function() {
    if (!this.team1.isAlive() || !this.team2.isAlive()) {
        if (this.team1.isAlive()) {
            alert("Team 1 is win");
        }
        if (this.team2.isAlive()) {
            alert("Team 2 is win");
        }
        console.log(`THE BATTLE IS END :
        ${this.team1.toString()}
        ${this.team2.toString()}
      ${this.team1.name} - ${this.team1.members.length} - 
${this.team1.members.map(n => n.currentHealth)}
      ${this.team2.name} - ${this.team2.members.length} -
${this.team2.members.map(n => n.currentHealth)}  
    `);
        return;
    }
    team1.kick(team2);
    team2.kick(team1);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.battle.bind(this));
};
var game = new Game(team1, team2);
game.battle();
```

Comment: Just clarifying, if it's the archers turn, they should attack the other archer. If that archer is dead, attack another class?

Comment: Also, every iteration of the for loop, you should check if thew targetTeam is alive as well, otehrwise there's a chance of runing an intinite loop

Comment: the logic of the goal search is to beat the hero of the same type while he is alive, and when he dies  search random target for the attack

Comment: Fixed a small typo, it should work now. I was using `targetTeam.length` and not `targetTeam.members.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these two little adjustments to your code. If I understand the question, this should do what you need.

```js
Unit.prototype.SelectSameType = function(targetTeam)
{ //Iterate through all the players and look for at least one of the same type that's alive
  for(let i = 0; i < targetTeam.members.length; i++)
  {
    let target = targetTeam.members[i];
    if(target.type === this.type && target.isAlive()) return target;
  }
  return null;
}
```

```js
Team.prototype.kick = function(targetTeam) {
    console.log(`\nTeam ${this.name} is attacking`);

    for(var i=0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
        var singleMember = this.members[i];

        if(!this.isAlive() || !targetTeam.isAlive()) break;
        if(!singleMember.isAlive()) continue;

        //Check for the same type first
        var target = singleMember.SelectSameType(targetTeam)
        if(target === null) target = this.selectRandomTarget(targetTeam);

        singleMember.kick(target);

    }
};
```

Comment: It does not work, all the same the heroes beat other heroes while the heroes of the same type are alive

Comment: How many iterations have you ran? Another thing to consider, is that the stats are constant, one team will always be stronger than the other, try randomizing the attack strength to vall between certain ranges.